# Accessing attributes of class instances passed as optional arguments

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, instance, argument-passing

I have two class instances which have list attributes, e.g.:

```
foo.range = [1,2]
bar.range = [3,4]
```

I also have a function which takes multiple arguments:

```
def permutations(*args):
    return list(itertools.product(arg.range for arg in args))
```

I want `permutations(foo, bar)` to return all permutations of those two (or more) lists (i.e. `[(1,3), (1,4) …]`) but I actually get `[([1, 2],), ([3, 4],)]`

Could someone please help me to understand where am I going wrong and how to achieve the result I'm hoping for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) expects the iterables as individual arguments(`itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])`), so you need to unpack the items to it using the the splat(**`*`**) operator:

```
>>> def permutations(*args):
        return list(itertools.product(*(arg.range for arg in args)))

>>> permutations(foo, bar)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Consider this simple function, it will collect all positional arguments passed to it in args:

```
>>> def func(*args):
    print args
    print list(args[0])
...
```

When we pass it a generator expression it is collected as one individual item in the `args` tuple:

```
>>> func(x for x in range(5))
(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fda2ab4e780>,)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To fix this we need to unpack our generator expression, also as somethine like `*x for x in range(5)` is not a valid syntax in Python, we need to add extra parenthesis around the generator expression:

```
>>> func(*(x for x in range(5)))
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
# Failed as expected for args[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-215-13af4340dad1>", line 1, in <module>
    func(*(x for x in range(5)))
  File "<ipython-input-213-08941e2a3c06>", line 3, in func
    print list(args[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for the resolution and the excellent explanation. I was very close, having realised that I needed to unpack the items but not knowing where to put the asterisk.